# Ubuntu terminal hangs after opening files

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 always hangs the terminal if I open a file like so:

```
#sublime index.php
```

any thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't know if this is ubuntu specific, but maybe this q makes more sense at http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

By default the terminal will run the program in the foreground, so you won't end up back at the shell until the program has finished. just do:

```
#sublime index.php &
```